# React: XMLHttpRequest returns a 404 error and file exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I was working on a React App when the problem happened. I was working with `XMLHttpRequest` to insert new information into a JSON file (with the `POST` method) but the server responded with a 404 status.

There are a few things that I want to mention:

1. My JSON file (called "Data.json") is in the React´s public folder.
2. My app is not hosted yet, so I opened it with npm start on a local host.
3. I´ve verified that the path is correct and there´s actually a JSON file in that direction.
4. The method post is executed when the user press a button, so it is sended after the page has fully loaded.
5. The function is correctly called, so there isn´t a problem with the event listener itself.

**Error:**

```
POST http://localhost:3000/Data.json 404 (Not Found)
```

**Javascript code:**

```
async function download() {

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    let url = "/Data.json"
    let obj = {
        "unlockedChars":API.unlockedChars,
        "completed":API.completed,
        "lastCompleted":API.lastCompleted
    }
    
    
    xhr.open("POST", url)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

**Data.json:**

```
[{
"unlockedChars":[{
    "id":"Ancient_One",
    "star":2,
    "duplicated":false
},
{
    "id":"Ancient_One",
    "star":3,
    "duplicated":true
}],
"completed":0,
"lastCompleted":0
}]
```

Comment: React App is not a server. You requested to the localhost:3000 local server not a React App. But, there is no running server. So, it returns 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the concepts.